# can't remove inline styles to seperate file in Nuxt3

Tags: css, build, bundle, vite, nuxtjs3

iam trying to remove inline styles from bundled html into seperate css file ,
i tried 2 solutions in `nuxt.config.ts`

1- to add build attribute inside vite config

2- to add build attribute in first level
both has no effect on styles .

```js
//nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({

  vite: {
    plugins: [vsharp()],
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          // additionalData: '@import "@/assets/sass/main-ltr.scss'
        }
      }
    },
    // trial 1
    build:{
      cssCodeSplit:false,
    },
  } ,
  // trial 2
  build:{
    extractCSS: true
  },

})
```